# How to compute for the time complexity of this triple nested loop

Tags: summation, computational-complexity

```
for (i=1 to n-1) {
  for (j=i+1 to n) {
    for (k=1 to j) {
    }
  }
}
```

The Answer is:
$$\frac{n^3}{3} - \frac{n}{3}$$

I'm trying to use summation to solve for it, but I'm having a bit of trouble:

$$\sum_i^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\sum_1^j$$

$$\sum_i^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j$$

$$\sum_i^{n-1}(i+1)+(i+2)+...(i+1+n)j$$

Stuck here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N}k=\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$
and
$$i(i+1)=\frac 13((i+2)(i+1)i-(i+1)i(i-1)),$$
we have

$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}j-\sum_{j=1}^{i}j\right)\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{i(i+1)}{2}\right)\\&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}(n-1)-\frac 12\cdot\frac 13\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left((i+2)(i+1)i-(i+1)i(i-1)\right)\\&=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{2}-\frac 16(n+1)n(n-1)\\&=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{3}\end{align}$$

Comment: Wow you should apply to Guinness book of records with that typing speed.

Comment: Is `i(i+1)=1/3((i+2)(i+1)i−(i+1)i(i−1))` an identity?

Comment: @Secret: Yes. Try expanding the right hand side.

Comment: @mathlove Yup indeed. I meant in what kind of identity, as I'm not sure it's an algebraic identity (in the sense of the word that it's on "lists of identities to remember"). Basically I'm just curious as to 'how did you know to use it identity', and is there any technique in uncovering what I should use?

Comment: @Secret: As you know, we can do as the following : $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i(i+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(i^2+i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i=\frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}+\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$. This has no problem. But I prefer the way in my answer especially when we have a product of consecutive numbers such as $i(i+1),i(i+1)(i+2)$. These can be written as the difference of consecutive numbers as the identity we are talking about. We can easily get the result because of the telescoping sum. I hope this helps.

Comment: @mathlove thank you, that's a big help for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a less algebraic proof .

The sum adds an $1$ for each triple $(i,j,k)$ such that $1 \leq i<j\leq n$ and $1 \leq k \leq j \leq n$ . First choose a $j$ from $1$ to $n$ . For each such $j$ there are $j-1$ choices for $i$ and $j$ choices for $k$ . So the sum is equivalent with :

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}j(j-1)=\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^2-\sum_{j=1}^{n} j=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n-2)}{6}=\frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{3}=\frac{n^3-n}{3}$$ as wanted .

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\color{darkblue}{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n}\color{green}{\sum_{k=1}^j 1}
&=\color{darkblue}{\sum_{1\le i < j\le n}}\color{green}j\\
&=\color{darkblue}{\sum_{j=2}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}}\color{green}j\\
&=\sum_{j=2}^n j(j-1)\\
&=2\sum_{j=2}^n \binom j2\\
&=2\binom {n+1}3\\
&=\frac {n(n^2-1)}3
&=\frac {n^3}3-\frac n3\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$